# org-mode File Specific Functions

Tags: emacs, org-mode, literate-programming, org-babel

I am working on a literate program in org-mode. I have couple of functions in my .emacs that I use to setup a repl for the program, is it possible to move these functions to the org-mode file and they are evaluated every time the file is opened (like buffer local vars but with functions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the special `eval` [file-local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) (emphasis mine):

> Some "variable names" have special meanings in a local variables list:
>
> - `mode` enables the specified major mode.
> - **`eval` evaluates the specified Lisp expression** (the value returned by that expression is ignored).
> - `coding` specifies the coding system for character code conversion of this file. See [Coding
>     Systems](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Coding-Systems.html#Coding-Systems).
> - `unibyte` says to load or compile a file of Emacs Lisp in unibyte mode, if the value is `t`. See [Disabling
>     Multibyte](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Disabling-Multibyte.html#Disabling-Multibyte).

So, for example, an Org file that has this first line

```
# -*- eval: (message "foo"); -*-
```

or a block like this within the last 3000 characters of the file

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (message "foo")
# End:
```

will evaluate `(message "foo")` when the file is opened.

This is a security risk, so you will be prompted when you open the file. You can use `y` to evaluate it once or `!` to save it as a safe evaluation in your custom file and avoid future prompts.

**Edit:**

This is a bit awkward, but here is a way to evaluate a named source block on file load:

```
# -*- eval: (progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "foo") (org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe)) -*-

#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
  (message "Yes, it worked")
#+END_SRC
```

Unfortunately I don't see any way to call the named block directly, and this way you get prompted for security *two times*: once for the `eval` and once for the code block `foo`.

Comment: is it possible to evaluate a named source block from an org file?

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya, I can't find a very clean way to do so, but I've updated my answer with something that seems to work.

Comment: `# -*- eval: (progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "foo") (org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe)) -*-` can be replaced with `# -*- eval: (org-sbe "foo") -*-`